# How to set user data for a QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I would like to set an integer number to be stored in a `QWidget`, and I think the `setUserData` member function would do the trick but I can't find any documentation. Any hints?

Comment: QObject::setUserData is marked as "internal" -- it's probably advisable to avoid using it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You might be looking for [`QObject::setProperty()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty) (which is of course inherited by [`QWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html)).

Comment: Is it possible to assign an object (say of class Foo) as a property and get it back when queried, instead of using just strings, ints or other simple data type properties?

Comment: I am not sure as I am not a QT expert. But the solution I posted below of creating a inherited type would certainly work for an arbitrary object. You would simple replace "Data" with "Foo".

Comment: @SexyBeast YES it is possible and makes all this very useful: you can have QVariant support arbitrary classes, as described here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/custom-types.html (with a nice example here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-tools-customtype-example.html)

Answer (score 11):

I am not an expert in  QT but why not just create a class that inherits from `QWidget` and has an integer?  Like so:

```
class MyDerivedWidget : public QWidget
{
    public:
  MyDerivedWidget();

    private:
  Data *myUserData;
};
```

Or if you insist on using the `setUserData` checkout the last post [here](http://www.qtforum.org/article/27363/qwidget-user-data.html).

Comment: It is, if you do explicit MyDerivedWidget(QWidget parent=0){}, simple and effective, still, it sounds a bit hacky to me, but useful answer so I voted up, thx.

Comment: IMO, this is the least hacky of the two answers. If you want to store data in a QWidget (vs just using a normal struct), the proper way would be to Inherit the class you want, add more functionality and do it 'right'. Atleast by inheriting, you'd be able to add accessors and the such to make it more useful than just passing a standard QWidget around with an additional random property...

Comment: @g19fanatic, respectfully disagree (and apparently the library designers are on my side, otherwise `setProperty()` wouldn't exist). Sometimes it can be very convenient to have a simple "bag of data" associated with an instance, without having to design and maintain a whole subclass just to get that.

Comment: @Barnabas I agree with g19fanatic inheritance is not "hacky" it is a fundamental feature of object-oriented programming. If you do not feel comfortable with inheritance I would strongly recommend looking into it and learning more. It is a very, very powerful tool.

Comment: @frederic Yeah I would agree with that as long as the "bag of data" remains simple.  If you are looking to add more then just a few primitvies though I think you should start thinking about inheritence.

Comment: @vannattab, thanks for your answer, let's not break the bits here. I did not mean to say too much, "hacky" could have been a bit strong.

Comment: setUserData is necessary because I have "class PieView : public QAbstractItemView" to which the compiler is refusing to let me add my own functions.